# Rails 4: Why assets are not working under development on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I have a project cloned from a repo and on my mac is working. But on the Ubuntu 16.04 machine no. The assets are broken and seem there are no errors. The same project works on a Mac machine from same repo.
I need to understand how to fix this and what could be the cause of Ubuntu to give this problem. In the console no errors. Just the assets are not working.

Rails 4.2.6

Comment: just a guess - did your assets compile when pushing? You make have to do that manually.

Comment: On Ubuntu, I did rake clobber and rake precompile but assets still not working. If you have some solutions please post maybe I can use before pushing to the repo again

Comment: check config/initializers/assets.rb. If you you are using different assets than application.css and application,js. you need to specify them here.

Comment: So the app is working everywhere but not on Ubuntu and I'm sharing 3 Pastebin of those files maybe I miss something:
https://pastebin.com/pkLZzeuY
https://pastebin.com/Rdva7iCz
https://pastebin.com/PiWLKMAC